# Get records based on row value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the records based on the row value. Please refer to the attached image for a table overview with records.

If there is no `Execution Project` in the column `projecttype` for a specific `ESAProjectID` then take the row with values
`projecttype='Group Project'` .

otherwise

if both `Execution Project` and `Group Project` are found for a specific `ESAProjectID` then
take only `projecttype='Execution Project'`

In the attached image I have marked in green color records are the expected result.
[image]

I tried this SQL but no luck

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ESAProjectID, a.projecttype
  FROM test1 a
 INNER JOIN test1 b
    ON a.ESAProjectID = b.ESAProjectID
 WHERE a.projecttype = 'Group Project'
```

Comment: Are 'Execution Project' and 'Group Project' the only possible values in the column `projecttype`?

Comment: @forpas Yes, these two are the field values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version of the DB is 8.0+, then you can count by using a window aggregation function per each ESAProjectID value such as

```
WITH tt AS
(
 SELECT t.*, 
        SUM(projecttype='Execution Project') OVER (PARTITION BY ESAProjectID) AS sm
   FROM test1 AS t
)
SELECT ESAProjectID, ProjectID, projecttype
  FROM tt
 WHERE sm > 0 AND projecttype = 'Execution Project'
    OR sm = 0 AND projecttype = 'Group Project'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eEu01MXz)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The demo looks to be working fine. Will check at my end and confirm

Comment: I suppose people downvoted that because you have used an image. People prefer having text data especially for SQL questions as handle them easy @ManiMuthuPandi . You might keep it a future reference. Have a nice study!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
select a.* from test1 a
    join
    (select ESAProjectID,
sum(case when projecttype = 'Execution Project' then 1 else 0 end) count
from test1 group by ESAProjectID) b
on (a.ESAProjectID = b.ESAProjectID)
where a.projecttype = (
    IF(b.count = 0, 'Group Project', 'Execution Project')
    );
```

Comment: thank you, its working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Since `'Execution Project'` and `'Group Project'` are the only possible values in the column `projecttype`, you can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.ESAProjectID, 
       t1.projecttype 
FROM test1 t1
WHERE t1.projecttype = 'Execution Project' 
   OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM test1 t2
     WHERE t2.ESAProjectID = t1.ESAProjectID 
       AND t2.projecttype = 'Execution Project'
   );
```